# How To Get Automatic Registration With Castle Windsor

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, auto-registration

I recently read [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/31/didja-know-merging-windsor-configuration-with-automatic-registration.aspx) on automatic registration working with XML Configuration. I would like to do exactly what he does, but his code snippet doesn't work for me. The Register method doesn't exist on my container object.

Here's his code:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
container.Register(
    AllTypes.Of(typeof (ConsumerOf<>))
        .FromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly)
    );
```

Is there a DLL reference I'm missing? Is Register() an extension method and I don't have the right namespace referenced? I've looked at the Castle Docs but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah! Nevermind. I'm using RC-3, and the Register() method is only in the trunk.